# Error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have error for code:

```
String sql = "CREATE USER ken IDENTIFIED BY 11;";

try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "system", "kenilyas");
    System.out.println("1111111111111");
    System.out.println("222222");
    pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    System.out.println("333333");
    try {
        System.out.println("333333");
        pst.execute();
        System.out.println("creating");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: Got any dignostic information (line numbers)? I guess that the `;` might be causing the problem, because Oracle-drivers tend to support only one statement within a query.

Comment: It *is* the ; that causes the problem.

Comment: @Caramiriel Yes you're right. Simple solution, but I was debugging for 30min before I turned to SO.

Answer (score 103):

The problem is `;`

```
sql = "CREATE USER ken IDENTIFIED BY 11;";
```

Remove the `;` from above string.

Comment: thank you! so silly to have systems not be flexible about this or not throwing a very clear expection

Comment: @Georgios And the system should accept that comma !

Comment: @Jarkid it's semicolon.

Answer (score 8):

I have also received same problem in myBatis.

**Error:**

```
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

    ; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

**Solution:**

```
select * from tableName where id= '123';
```

after removing `";"` from Where clause(Mybatis Mapper xml), its working.